# Launch GDB in layout split mode

Tags: gdb

Every time I launch GDB, I hit `ctrl+x ctrl+2` to enter `layout split` mode. I'd like to just launch directly into split mode, so I added `set layout split` to my `.gdbinit` file, but this appears to have no effect. How do I launch directly into layout split mode every time?

Comment: It's just `layout split`, not `set layout split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `set layout ...`, it's just `layout ...`, so you want to add `layout split` to `.gdbinit`.

What you might find though, is that you have some weird issues with the pager, so GDB might get confused and think the console is full and prompt you to press return to see the rest of the text, even though the console is clearly not yet full.

To work around this, I would suggest you add this to your `.gdbinit`:

```
with height 0 -- layout split
```

this will work for GDB 9 and later.